# What would be 1 hour equivalent on these moons of Jupiter and Saturn compared to earth? And their astrobiological implications

Tags: cosmology, natural-satellites, time-dilation, astrobiology, galilean-moons

Considering the distance from and velocity of Sun, Saturn, Jupiter, thermal energy due to motion other than that adding/combining to velocity, and the individual mass and velocity of the particular moons and our earth,
1 hour on earth equals how many hours on the following particular moons of Saturn and Jupiter,

1. Europa
2. Io
3. Titan
4. Enceladus
5. Callisto
6. Ganymede
7. Rhea
8. Iapetus
9. Dione
10. Tethys

*Or in a more easy way, a link to a webpage where this is already calculated*

Also most importantly, what will be the implications of this on evolution of possible life as compared to our time perspective?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I literally have no idea what you are asking. What property do you talk about? What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Earth hour is equal to one hour on each of those moons, to a very high level of accuracy.

Relativistic time dilation is a real and measurable thing, but you need extremely accurate clocks to measure it. It would cause clocks to disagree by a few microseconds a day.

The moons of Jupiter and Saturn are further from the sun, and even though close to their planets, they are at a higher gravitational potential than the surface of the Earth (see [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/681_large/)) and so clocks would run slightly fast, that is one hour on these moons might be 1 hr, 0 min 0.00001 seconds.

There are no astrobiological implications.

Answer (score 3):

The difference will not be constant, since the Earth moves around the Sun the relative velocity of all of those bodies change.  You might want to look into Barycentric Dynamic Time (TDB), which is time measured from the solar system barycenter which was developed specifically to avoid the complications of all of the bodies having slightly differing timescales.

At any given time, the difference between TDB and atomic time on Earth is only a very tiny fraction of a second.  It would be even less as you moved to the outer planets.  On average, over the course of any planet's year, the differences cancel out to zero.  This is because it will experience time slightly faster in one point of it's orbit, but at the opposite of that point, when it is moving exactly the opposite direction, it will experience slower time.

Comment: Can’t we tick more than one answer on this site?